# Generating random numbers from arbitrary probability density function

Tags: python, random, statistics

I would like to be able to generate random numbers with a probability density function that comes from a drawn curve. These two below have the same area under the curve but should produce lists of random numbers with different characteristics.

[image]

My intuition is that one way would be to do it is to sample the curve, and then use the areas of those rectangles to feed an `np.random.choice` to pick a range to do an ordinary random in the range of that rectangle's range.

[image]

This doesn't feel like a very efficient way to do it. Is there a more 'correct' way to do it?

I had a crack at actually doing it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

areas = [4.397498, 4.417111, 4.538467, 4.735034, 4.990129, 5.292455, 5.633938,
         6.008574, 6.41175, 5.888393, 2.861898, 2.347887, 2.459234, 2.494357,
         2.502986, 2.511614, 2.520243, 2.528872, 2.537501, 2.546129, 7.223747,
         7.223747, 2.448148, 1.978746, 1.750221, 1.659351, 1.669999]
divisons = [0.0, 0.037037, 0.074074, 0.111111, 0.148148, 0.185185, 0.222222,
            0.259259, 0.296296, 0.333333, 0.37037, 0.407407, 0.444444, 0.481481,
            0.518519, 0.555556, 0.592593, 0.62963, 0.666667, 0.703704, 0.740741,
            0.777778, 0.814815, 0.851852, 0.888889, 0.925926, 0.962963, 1.0]
weights = [a/sum(areas) for a in areas]
indexes = np.random.choice(range(len(areas)), 50000, p=weights)
samples = []
for i in indexes:
    samples.append(np.random.uniform(divisons[i], divisons[i+1]))

binwidth = 0.02
binSize = np.arange(min(samples), max(samples) + binwidth, binwidth)
plt.hist(samples, bins=binSize)
plt.xlim(xmax=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The method seems to work, but is a bit heavy!

Comment: Are you saying you just have an image file with that curve?  Or do you actually have numbers representing the coordinates of points on the curve?

Comment: It could be either. It could be an image file, but more likely a drawn curve. Either svg or some kind of inking thing on a touch screen.

Comment: An SVG is an image file.  If it's drawn on a screen, then how is your program accessing it?  I'm asking what the data *format* is that your program will be using, not how the thing is created.'

Comment: It's quite hypothetical at the moment. I'm prototyping it in a CAD program, but it could end up anywhere.  I assumed you meant a bitmap, one can access the coords in an SVG curve. (Eventually!)

Comment: Mathematically speaking, what I would do is integrate the PDF to get the cumulative distribution function.  If you then invert that, you get a function into which you can plug a random number in [0, 1] and effectively get a value from the original distribution.  How you actually do that depends on the format of your data.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use **rv_continuous** from **scipy.stats**. The straightforward way to begin would be to approximate one of those pdf's with a a collection of splines with **rv_continuous**. In fact, you can generate pseudorandom deviates by defining either a pdf or a cdf with this thing.

Answer (score 2):

For your case, it seems like histogram-based approach would definitely be easiest since you have a line that the user has drawn.

But since you're just trying to generate random numbers from that distribution, you can use the normalized y-values (sum the y-position of all pixels and divide by the total) as the probability_distribution directly in the function below and just take arrays the size of the number of pixels the user has drawn.

```
from numpy.random import choice
pde = choice(list_of_candidates, number_of_items_to_pick, p=probability_distribution)
```

probability_distribution (the normalized pixel y-values) is a sequence in the same order of list_of_candidates (the associated x-values). You can also use the keyword replace=False to change the behavior so that drawn items are not replaced.

[see numpy docs here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

This should be much faster since you're not actually generating an entire pde, just drawing random numbers that match the pde.

EDIT: your update looks like a solid approach. If you do want to generate the pde, you might consider investigating numba (http://numba.pydata.org) to vectorize your for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to sample the inverse of the CDF. Then you use a uniform random generator to generate p values on the x-axis of the inverse CDF to generate random draws of your PDF.
See this article: http://matlabtricks.com/post-44/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-distribution

Comment: Your link is now broken. I added an explicit self-contained code in my answer to make your proposition more concrete

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with `rv_continuous`, so I made my own little routine to sample from any continuous distribution with compact support, e.g. from a sum of two exponentials, or from any known discrete pdf (as asked in the question).
This is essentially @Jan 's solution (a pretty classic solution).

My code is fully self-contained.
To adapt it to any other distribution, you only need to change the formula in unnormalized_pdf, and make sure the boundaries of your support are correctly set (in my case from 0 to 10/lambda_max is enough.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

## The function may be any function, so long as it is with FINITE Support
def unnormalized_pdf(T, lambda1, intercept1, lambda2, intercept2):
    return np.exp(-lambda1 * T - intercept1) + np.exp(-lambda2 * T - intercept2)


lambda1, intercept1, lambda2, intercept2 = (
    0.0012941708402716523,
    8.435217547457713,
    0.0063804460354380385,
    6.712937938322769,
)

## defining the support of the pdf by hand
x0 = 0
xmax = max(1 / lambda1, 1 / lambda2) * 10

## the more bins, the higher the precision
Nbins = 1000000
xs = np.linspace(x0, xmax, Nbins)
dx = xs[1] - xs[0]
## other way to specify it:
# dx = min(1/lambda1, 1/lambda2)/100
# xs = np.arange(x0, xmax, dx)

## compute the (approximate) pdf and cdf of the thing to sample:
pdf = unnormalized_pdf(xs, lambda1, intercept1, lambda2, intercept2)
normalized_pdf = pdf / pdf.sum()
cdf = np.cumsum(normalized_pdf)

## sampling from the distro
Nsamples = 100000
r = np.random.random(Nsamples)
indices_in_cdf = np.searchsorted(cdf, r)
values_drawn = xs[indices_in_cdf]
histo, bins = np.histogram(values_drawn, 1000, density=True)
plt.semilogy(bins[:-1], histo, label="drawn from distro", color="blue")
plt.semilogy(xs, normalized_pdf / dx, label="exact pdf from which we sample", color="k", lw=3)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition to sample with weights proportional to the density is fine as an approximation. I recommend to use tools to invert the distribution function after integrating the density. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.sampling import NumericalInversePolynomial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad


class MyDist:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def support(self):
        # distribution restricted to 0, 5, can be changed as needed
        return (0, 5)

    def pdf(self, x):
        # this is not a proper pdf, the normalizing
        # constant is missing (does not integrate to one)
        # this is ok for the method presented here
        return x * (x + np.sin(5*x) + 2) * np.exp(-x**self.a)


dist = MyDist(0.5)
gen = NumericalInversePolynomial(dist)

# compute the missing normalizing constant to plot the pdf
const_pdf = quad(dist.pdf, *dist.support())[0]

r = gen.rvs(size=50000)
x = np.linspace(r.min(), r.max(), 500)

# show histogram together with the pdf
plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x) / const_pdf)
plt.hist(r, density=True, bins=100)
plt.show()
```

[image: Samples and density]

There are more tools to sample from custom continuous or discrete univariate distributions by just providing some information about the distribution, such as the density / pdf. Overview of the different methods:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.sampling.html